# What is the solution to the following limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to solve the following limit problem?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3x^2+\sin x}{x^2+(\sin x)^2}$$. I have tried the following and arrived at a solution. But not sure if it is correct.

Applying L'Hospital's rule taking derivative thrice I get the following expression:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\cos x}{8\cos 2x} = 0$$

Comment: I do not think you can apply L'Hospital three times here

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: since $|sin(x)|\le 1$ the dominant term would be only the $3x^2$ and $x^2$ in the nominator and denominator, and therefore the limit result is $3$

Comment: You can apply L'Hospital if both numerator and denominator tend to either zero or infinity so what happens after you apply it two times?

Comment: @Vasya You can't even apply it two times because the limit produced doesn't exist in the second application.

Comment: @PeterForeman: Isn't it still going be infinity by infinity after the first application? What am I missing?

Comment: @Vasya Yes but L'Hôpital's rule can only be applied if the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ also exists. In the second case it doesn't and so we cannot equate a non-existent limit with an existing limit. For example$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+\sin{(x)}}=1\ne\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\cos{(x)}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write $$\frac{3+\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}}{1+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use *asymptotic equivalence*: as a sine is bounded, $3x^2+\sin x\sim_\infty 3x^2$, $x^2+\sin^2x\sim_\infty x^2$, so
$$ \frac{3x^2+\sin x}{x^2+\sin^2x}\sim_\infty \frac{3\not x^2}{\not x^2}=3. $$